# Can you statically assert that object can be converted to a certain type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm currently working on a console GUI library for C++11 just to ease some debugging and stuff.

For a certain class that templates, I want to make sure I can convert the templated type to string before I print it.

### Example:

```
template<typename T>
class listbox {
private:
    std::vector<T> list;
    [...]

public:
    std::string print_item(T& item) { /* static_assert() here */}
}
```

So in the "Static Assert" part I want to check if I can convert an item to `std::string` (or `const char*` would work as well), so really the question is simple, how do I assert a conversion from a templated type?

I know the compiler/ide would react to types not being able recognize it,
but I need a fixed type there to be able to have more control of the string.

Comment: Simply why don't you print out with std::ostream directly your item ? If you cannot convert it then it won't compile.

Comment: @coincoin I'm not sure about his intention. But `int` isn't convertible to `std::string` but it can be accepted as a parameter for `std::ostream`

Comment: my intentions was to create objects that can be printed out with ostream in forms of gui elements:
`cio::textbox box();`
`box << "Something" << 3.25;`
`cout << box.offset(10).size(25, 35) << label("Hello").offset(0,0).size(cio::anchor::right, 0);`


Well it's not final atm, not sure entirely how to do input in a good manner.

Comment: I was looking into to maybe control an output stream, but the thing is, if you want persistant lists, its better to make them variables, if could do both, however that means i would need to make new ostreams to maybe output directly textboxes/etc or something. Not entirely sure if i want that tbh.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can! Just use [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible)

```
template<typename T>
class listbox {
private:
    std::vector<T> list;
    [...]

public:
    std::string print_item(T& item) {
      static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, const char*>::value, "Not stingifyable");
      // More work
    }
}
```

Comment: He indicated C++11 only, it's better to `static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, const char*>::value);` instead. `std::is_convertible_v` will be added in C++17

Comment: And to add a failure message.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the quick awnser!
Have a pleasant day and a rep point.

Comment: @Danh, Thanks. Although rolling out your own `is_convertible_v` until c++17 is out in its final form isn't too difficult.

Comment: @StoryTeller Although wouldn't that require variable templates, which are a C++14 feature?

Comment: Yes, variable template is a C++14 feature, we need at least C++14 to use it. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template

Comment: @TartanLlama, well yeah. I forgot some compiler vendors are still being difficult.

Comment: Hmm, havent really read about variable templates,  i assume that this `std::is_convertible<T, const char*>::value` would work on c++11?

Comment: @Ivan Correct. `std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value` would also work.